# Describe the multiples of $21$ that ends with $241$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Honestly, I have no idea how to proceed in this. I tried to combine both divisibilities critirea of $3$ and $7$, and tried to get a general form for a number being a multiple of $3$ and $7$, but I couldn't get any (and I wasn't hopeful).

If anyone could help me, I would be grateful!

Comment: $x \equiv 0 \pmod {21}, \; \; $ $x \equiv 241 \pmod {1000}$

Comment: Notice that $\mbox{gcd}(1000,21) =1$ and use chinese remainder theorem. It guarantees that the system of linear congruences given by @WillJagy has a unique solution modulo $N = 21\times 1000$

Comment: You want to find whole number solutions of $21x = 1000y + 241$. Do you know how to find all the whole number solutions of $21x - 1000y = 1$?

Comment: If you have one $x, y$ pair that's a solution to $21x = 1000y + 241$ then we can also say $21(x + 1000k) = 1000(y + 21k) + 241$ for any $k$.

Comment: @Robson: Please stop making limits in titles taller by using the `\limits` switch. The goal is to make titles as short as possible. That kind of edit is great in the body, where I agree it's more readable. But if you make the title taller, it takes up too much space in the Questions list. It's frowned on here at M.SE.

Comment: @AdrianKeister ok!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you have
$$x=21a\\x=1000b+241$$
where $a,b,x\in\mathbb N$. It is true for $x=17241,a=821,b=17$.

As I know, there is no known method to obtain all possible solutions if you, in general, replace $21$ and $1000$ with some arbitrary numbers. However, according to the Chinese Remainer Theorem, if the greatest common divisor of the two given numbers is $1$, it then has unique solution modulo $a\cdot b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are the given numbers), as math.h explained in the comment. Therefore, finding one example basically solves the problem.

Comment: I don't feel like this really answers the question asked. It gives one example, but doesn't describe the general case or describe how this answer was obtained.

Comment: @MiloBrandt. As I know, there is no known method to obtain all possible solutions if you, in general, replace $21$ and $1000$ with some arbitrary numbers. However, according to the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), if the greatest common divisor of the two given numbers is $1$, it then has unique solution modulo $a\cdot b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are the given numbers), as math.h explained in the comment. Therefore, finding one example basically solves the problem.

Comment: That comment would make a nice addition to the answer, I think - I meant that the answer didn't mention that periodicity. (Though, to be sure, there is a way to use the CRT constructively in the general case, so long as you're willing to compute multiplicative inverses mod $a$ and $b$ - which may be done with the Euclidean algorithm)

Comment: @MiloBrandt. Ok, I included the comment in the post.

Answer (score 10):

In your shoes, I would have tried Wolfram Alpha. Something like `solve 21x = 241 mod 1000` should give you the answer:

> $x = 821 + 1000n$ and $n \in \mathbb Z$

Well, that needs to be qualified with $n \geq 0$, since negative $n$ give numbers like $-3759$. Positive $n$, and 0, will give you the numbers you want: 17241, 59241, 80241, etc.

Also observe that the last three digits of multiples of 21 cycle at every thousand, which is a bit longer than, say, multiples of 22 (which cycle the last three digits every five hundred multiples).